# Get List Count property

Tags: c#, class

I have two classes :

```
public class a
{
    public List<b> b { get; set; }

    public c c { get; set; }
}

public class c
{
    public int count { get {  return ?????????? } }
}
```

I want to return the `Count` property of `a.b` in my class `c`

Comment: Can you try "public static class a", and then try to reach by a.b.Count?

Comment: As it is now, `c` can be used in places where there is no relevant `a`. We might be able to help if you give us a higher-level idea on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `a` a dependency of `c` and access `b` from there

```
public class a
{
    public a() {
        b = new List<b>();
        c = new c(this);
    }

    public List<b> b { get; set; }

    public c c { get; set; }
}

public class c
{
    private a _a;
    public c(a _a) { this._a = _a; }

    public int count { get {  return _a.b.Count; } }
}
```